# How do I determine the size of a pdf with pdf.js so I can scale to the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I need to scale a pdf so it fills the height of the screen, but all I've found is the function `scale()`. How do i know how much to scale it?

Comment: Are you referring to a single page or complete pdf file?

Comment: @Mr_Green I hadn't thought about the possibility of each page being a different size. I'd want to scale each page (as the user goes ot that page) to be the height of the screen.

Comment: @Mr_Green I solved it. You can see my answer below.

Comment: Upvoted.. I was looking for a similar solution. thanks. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green NP. The documentation on PDF.js is lacking so I understand. It's a bit of a treasure hunt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To determine the width/height of a page, you need to do the following:

1. Get the page
2. In a "promise" function (the page can only be retrieved asynchronously):

   a. Retrieve the viewport with a scale of `1`

   b. Call the `width` property of the viewport

The Code:

```
//Get the page with your callback
pdf.getPage(1).then( function(page) {

    //We need to pass it a scale for "getViewport" to work
    var scale = 1;

    //Grab the viewport with original scale
    var viewport = page.getViewport( 1 );

    //Here's the width and height
    console.log( "Width: " + viewport.width + ", Height: " + viewport.height );
});
```